# Reference request for proof of Brodskii-Milman theorem "On the center of a convex set"

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Can anyone help me to access the paper:

> M.S Brodskii and D.P Milman, "On the center of a convex set", *Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR* 59 (1948) 837–840 in Russian?

or to prove the theorem:

> If $K$ is a weakly compact, bounded convex subset of a Banach space with normal structure, then there exists $x_0\in K$ such that $T(x_0)=x_0$ for all surjective isometry $T:K→K$. That is, there is a common fixed point for the family of surjective isometries on $K$.

Thank you.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance (Google didn't help me), but would you define *normal structure* for Banach spaces? (BTW, would the group of isometries be compact?).

Comment: @Włodzimierz Holsztyński Google helped me a bit: see http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102985731 or the free pdf http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102985731 .

Comment: Thank you. This link helped me to enhance my knowledge of normal structure.

Comment: @TaQ, thank you. I'll check the link which you have provided (but first I need some sleep :-).

Comment: Actually, I saw this link from the beginning. I don't think I have any access to it (?).

Comment: @Włodzimierz From http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965904817452 `The W*-convexity and normal structure in banach spaces´, *Applied Mathematics Letters*, **17** (12) 2004, pp. 1381–1386, Def. 1: A bounded, convex subset $K$ of a Banach space $X$ is said to *have normal structure* if every convex subset $H$ of $K$ that contains more than one point contains a point $x_0\in H$ such that $\sup\,\{\,\|\,x_0-y\,\|:y\in H\,\}<\sup\,\{\,\|\,x-y\,\|:x,y\in H\,\}$ . A Banach space $X$ is said to *have normal structure* if every bounded, convex subset of $X$ has normal structure.

Comment: The definition can also be found in (SpringerOpen) `[Normal Structure and Common Fixed Point Properties for Semigroups of Nonexpansive Mappings in Banach Spaces](http://www.fixedpointtheoryandapplications.com/content/2010/1/580956)´.

Comment: @TaQ, you're very kind. Many thanks.

Comment: Under the above definition & notation (just here copied by @TaQ) let me define the Banach $\ I_B\ $ interior operation: $\ I_B(H) := \{x\in H: \sup_{y\in H} ||x-y|| < \sup_{y\ z\in H} ||y-z||\}.\ $. Thus a Banach space has a normal structure $\ \Leftrightarrow\ $ every convex bounded (and closed?) set $\ H\subseteq X\ $ which has at least two different points (i.e. has positive linear dimension) has non-empty Banach interior. Did I make sense? I would introduce name: $\ X\ $ has an ***internal structure*** (-- or ***Banach internal structure***).

Answer (score 2):

An extension was published in the Taiwanese journal of math in 2009: journal.taiwanmathsoc.org.tw/index.php/tjm/article/download/507/383

I assume (but am not certain) that the original theorem is proved there also

Comment: Thank You. Your reference helped to get the ideas of the proof of the Brodskii-Milman theorem.

Comment: Link rot has struck and the link in this answer no longer works (2021).  It's volume 13, issue 2A for anyone searching, and the paper is called *Weak and weak$^*$ topologies and Brodskii-Milman's theorem on hyperspaces* by Thakyin Hu and Jui-Chi Huang.  A currently functioning link to the volume is: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/taiwanese-journal-of-mathematics/volume-13/issue-2A